# Rails 3: Manipulating devise "resource" in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise & devise_invitable in a rails 3 project, and I'm trying to manipulate some of the 'User' object fields in the devise controller.

The action is question is this:

```
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.accept_invitation!(params[resource_name])

    resource.first_name = 'Lemmechangethis'

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, :location => after_accept_path_for(resource)
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :edit }
    end
  end
```

I'd have thought that the (commented out) resource.first_name call would influence resource in much the same way as a model - but it doesn't seem to. I'm still getting a 'blank' validation error on this form.

So, the question is, how do I specify values to the User model in devise (and/or devise_invitable) that will actually be subject to verification?

Any suggestions appreciated,
                              John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resource` does return a User models instance. So the `resource.first_name = 'Lemmechangethis'` statement does change your User models instance but it doesnot trigger your User models validations, which is probably why `resource.errors` always returns an empty array. One way to trigger the User models validation is to call `resource.valid?` for example. You can then check the `resource.errors` array for specific error messages.

Comment: hey thanks guys but do you know where i learn more about 'resource'?